# Laggy youtube videos

Tags: sound, lubuntu, video, amd-graphics, youtube

I have problem with youtube videos. I am using lubuntu 22.04. My specs of laptop are
CPU: amd e350 dual core 1.60 GHZ
Graphics: Ati radeon hd 6310
RAM: 6gb
Everyting other works fluently, surfing on the net, etc... but just youtube videos making problem. It's not smooth as on windows for example. I mention that while i am watching videos, sound is going ok, but videos making problem. I am using Chrome on Lubuntu instead of Mozilla. I installed ubuntu-restricted-extras package, mesa repository etc..., and i really haven't idea what could be problem. I also tried to play youtube videos via VLC, but it's the same result, even worse. So any suggestions will be helpfull and i will be gratefull.
Thanks in Advance.
Mihajlov Nenad. :)

Comment: I don't know if this will improve your issue, but I find increasing swap can make a difference. Lubuntu installs with 22.04 media create a small swapfile, where increasing size can have an improvement (refer https://discourse.lubuntu.me/t/swap-and-lubuntu-faq/2591)   *I'm unsure if the issue you describe relates to lack of RAM (swap), screen tearing or something else sorry, so this may not be your issue*

Comment: Thx for your reply, i will try that to increase swap memory size ;) @guiverc

Answer (score 1):

For YouTube playback via the browser on the E-350, an extension like h.264ify and making sure gpu acceleration for video decoding is enabled for the browser can help. A player like MPV is recommended though.

Regards,

Comment: Thx Ahmed for reply, i will try your solution :D